# program to dial land phone, enter password and record?

Tags: command-line, recording, voip, sip, telephony

is there a program for **Windows** (or linux command line) platform that would do below from a command line?

- **call** a land phone number (using my SIP account)
- **enter** password
- **record** the call
- **finishes** after a period of time or after the other part hangs up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux command line:

`linphone` includes a scriptable `linphonec` command-line version. Starting `linphonec` with the `--pipe` option will create a socket in `/tmp` that one can write to and read from.

It fulfills all your requirements and I've tested (for my own uses) all of them successfully:

- Calling via SIP,
- transmitting DTMF sequences,
- recording a call to file, and
- via parsing its output, you can see when the call finishes and quit the program.

You'd do a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
socket=/tmp/linphonec-$(id -u)
filename=$HOME/record
number=123456789
passfile=$HOME/1234.wav

linphonec --pipe 2>&1 |
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
    case $line in
        *Ready )
            sleep 1
            echo ">>> initializing"
            for command in \
                "soundcard use files" \
                "record $filename" \
                "call $number"
            do
                echo -n $command | nc -q 5 -U $socket
            done
            ;;
        *Call\ *\ with\ *\ connected. )
            sleep 1
            echo ">>> sending pass"
            echo -n "play $passfile" | nc -q 5 -U $socket
            ;;
        *Call\ *\ ended. )
            sleep 1
            echo ">>> quitting"
            while echo -n quit | nc -q 5 -U $socket 2>&-
            do
                i=$(expr $i + 1)
                if test $i -ge 5
                then
                    echo $(basename $0): could not shut down linphonec >&2
                    exit 1
                fi
                sleep 2
            done
            echo ">>> END"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

This is not yet on optimal solution. Note that under `>>> sending pass`, I'm playing a wav file instead of sending a DTMF sequence. `linphone` is capable of the latter, but during my cursory fiddling I haven't yet found the right way to do so while sound in- and output is on file basis to allow recording.

Sadly, linphone documentation is sparse. I've had best results just starting `linphonec` interactively and using the builtin `help`.

Comment: sounds really great. Could you give me some hint about the "via parsing its output, you can see when the call finishes and quit the program." I cannot grasp what it could mean. The rest be in readme or online help I guess.

Comment: The credentials can be put inside the configured file specified with the `-c` option. The number to call can be specified with `-s`.

Comment: @peth In `while echo -n quit | nc -q 5 -U $socket 2&>-`, what condition evaluates to true/false? Also, what does `2&>-` mean? For me, the expression evaluates to false but linphonec remains running. It's a pity the there is no option for linphonec to exit after a call hangs up.

Comment: @OldGeezer I don't know if the whole of this works anymore, but it relies on a) linphone removing its control socket when it shuts down and b) `nc` returning an error when it can't write to the socket. (`2&>-` was supposed to read `2>&-` which closes the `stderr` output stream to suppress repeated output. It's purely cosmetic.) In other words, the loop repeatedly tells linphone to quit until it no longer listens.